# Não inserir annotations repetidos no mapa

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou inserindo alguns *annotations* q estão vindo de um servidor `JSON`, mas eu queria verificar se o *annotation* já está no mapa, se sim, não adiciona ele novamente. Pois eles estão sendo adicionados um sobre o outro. Tem como alguém me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Meu código adicionando os *pins*:

```
  // adiciona produtos ao mapa
    - (void)adicionaAnnotationsNoMapa:(id)objetos{
        NSMutableArray *annotationsPins = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *annotationDeProdutos in objetos) {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
            AnnotationMap *myAnn;
            myAnn = [[AnnotationMap alloc] init];
            location.latitude = [[annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
            location.longitude = [[annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
            myAnn.coordinate = location;
            myAnn.title = [annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"name"];
            myAnn.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R$ %@",[annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"price"]];
            myAnn.categoria = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"id_categoria"]];
            myAnn.idProduto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [annotationDeProdutos objectForKey:@"id"]];
            [annotationsPins addObject:myAnn];
        }

        [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotationsPins];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro desta iteração `for` que você faz, logo após atribuir os valores de latitude e longitude, você pode utilizar algo como bloco para isso, assim fazendo a comparação baseado na distância entre a coordenada a ser inserida com as que já existem no *array*.

Algo assim:

```
__block NSInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;

[annotationsPins enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(AnnotationMap *annotation, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
    CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:annotation.coordinate.longitude];

    if ([loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2] <= 5.0f) {
        foundIndex = idx;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];

if (foundIndex != NSNotFound) {
    // Achou coordenada, não faz as linhas abaixo
    continue;
}

// Prossegue iteração
```

O que acontece aqui é o seguinte: você utiliza o bloco do tipo `enumerate` para vasculhar o seu array annotationsPins e buscar alguma coordenada que esteja a uma distância menor do que *5 metros* da coordenada atual (**loc1**). Caso positivo, você interrompe o bloco e prossegue.

Se `foundIndex` for diferente de `NSNotFound`, significa que encontrou coordenada semelhante, então não precisa continuar o que tem no `for` pra baixo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeito. Eu so adicionei um `if` para verificar se tem algum `pin` no mapa, pois ele não estava conseguindo verificar a primeira vez pois n tinha nada no mapa. Tem como eu colocar a resolução do código aqui? pois sou novo no stack.

Comment: Ótimo! Considere marcar esta resposta como aceita caso tenha respondido sua dúvida. Assim irá ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida.